# Why doesn't the BizTalk 2009 SMTP Adapter support BCC and Priority?

Tags: smtp, biztalk, adapter, biztalk-2009

When looking at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560648(BTS.10).aspx I couldn't find BCC or Priority, so I'm sure it's not supported.

But why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the **why** of BCC and Priority missing from the SMTP Adapter, no idea I'm afraid - it has been missing from BizTalk since the first release of the product. You'd probably have to ask the BizTalk product team and I imagine they would just shrug.

There are however, a couple of work-arounds to add in the BCC and priority.

The first work around is an out and out hack, but fast to implement - send two emails, with the second being your BCC list that mentions that it is a BCC. Ugly and sure to come back and bite you. (this only works for the priority)

The second way is more *correct* but also more work - create your own SMTP adapter that supports these properties. The `System.Net.Mail` namespace contains all you will need to roll your own adapter that supports BCC.

The code example below comes from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.bcc.aspx):

```
MailAddress from = new MailAddress("ben@contoso.com", "Ben Miller");
MailAddress to = new MailAddress("jane@contoso.com", "Jane Clayton");
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
message.Subject = "Using the SmtpClient class.";
message.Body = @"The body test to send.";
message.Priority = MailPriority.High;

MailAddress bcc = new MailAddress("manager1@contoso.com");
message.Bcc.Add(bcc);

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(server);
client.Send(message);
```

You could even avoid the overhead of an adapter and implement this as a referenced assembly - the downside of doing it that way is that when using an adapter you automatically get plugged into the BizTalk messaging framework and its features such as tracking.